# Java InputStream is blocked

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a little problem with my InputStream.

Here the code :

```
public byte[] getBytes(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int read = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while ( 0 < (read = in.read(buffer))) {
            Log.v(TAG,"buffering...");
            out.write(buffer,0,read);
            Log.v(TAG, "bufffered data size : "+out.size());
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "close out");
        out.close();
        Log.v(TAG, "getBytes finish");
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
```

In my logs I have "buffering..." and the data size until the length of the byte array i send but when the size is the max, nothing happen. No error, no crash, juste nothing, like if we stay in the while without make the loop...

Someone have any idea ?

And... sorry for my english.

**Edit:**

I added

```
if(is.available()==0){
    Log.v(TAG, "time to sleep");
    Thread.sleep(200);
    if(is.available()==0)
        break;
}
```

at the end of my while and it work !

Thank you for your help guys !

Comment: `read` can block until input is available.

Comment: What are you passing as `InputStream in`? If it's a socket it could just be waiting for more data to arrive.

Comment: look at this example!
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/GetbytesfromInputStream.htm

Comment: @JimGarrison I pass a byte array by bluetooth.

Comment: @Aayush I look this and I back.

Comment: @Aayush I don't understand all this code, I begin with Androïd (and java), but i tried and it doesn't work. In any case, thank :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, `in.read(buffer)` will block until it receives data, it reaches the end of the file, or an exception is thrown (from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29)). My guess is that its still just waiting on more input from the InputStream.

Also, you should close the input stream after you finish reading from it.

Comment: How can I know if the read is finish ? I see it in the logs but I don't know the size of data before. I transfert a Bitmap, so the size is various.

Comment: I tried to add 

    if(is.available()>0)
    break;

at the end of the while but it breaks the loop before then end.

Comment: A lot of the time files contain some metadata which describes the size of the file... You can also just keep reading bytes and store them in some sort of dynamically sized data structure, like ArrayList.